# Relation between rad(G) , Δ(G) and |G| in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a formula for resolving the following question : "Given a graph G with rad(G) = 3 and Δ(G) = 5, can we have |G| = 2006?"

rad(G) is  is the minimum graph eccentricity of any vertex in G.(The eccentricity is the maximum graph between v and any other vertex u of G)

Δ(G) is the maximum degree in G(a degree of a vertex is the nr. of edges at it)

|G| is the nr. of vertices

I was thinking using the theorem "The number of vertices of odd degree in any graph G is even". By this, it can be |G| = 2006 if Δ(G) = 5, but how can I use the rad(G) as well?

Comment: What are you guessing? Any ideas? Also, this should go on math or cs.

Comment: And my apologies for getting the migration mucked up there..

Comment: Even if you know what they mean it could greatly help to include the definitions, or at least the name. Notations are not that standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in a graph of maximum degree $d$, for a fixed vertex $v$ there are

- at most $d$ vertexes at distance $1$ from $v$,
- at most $d(d-1)$ vertexes at distance $2$ from $v$,
- at most $d(d-1)^2$ vertexes at distance $3$ from $v$,
- and so on.

Take $v$ a vertex that is a "center" so has distance at most $3$ to each other vertex and do the calculation. (Do not forget $v$ itself.)

Answer (score -2):

If it is radius = 3  and diameter = 5 according to

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73901167

there is no reason why such a graph could not be constructed.

Comment: From the abstract, that paper is about a relationship between radius and diameter, not radius, maximum degree and number of vertices.